# Assemble.io assemble-middleware-permalinks not working, no output for assemble task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, permalinks, assemble

EDIT: Solved, see below.

Having trouble getting 'pretty URLs' to work with Assemble.io based site. With assemble-middleware-permalinks commented out it assembles the pages just fine into my specified folder (as index.html, about.html etc).

Full console output:

```
# grunt

Running "clean:build" (clean) task
Cleaning ./dist...OK

Running "copy:assets" (copy) task
Created 2 directories, copied 13 files

Running "uglify:vendor" (uglify) task
File ./dist/development/assets/js/components.js created: 129.64 kB → 128.88 kB

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File dist/development/assets/css/main.css created.

Running "assemble:pages" (assemble) task

#
```

My assemble task:

```
assemble: {

  options: {
    flatten: true,
    plugins: [
      'assemble-contrib-permalinks',
      'assemble-middleware-sitemap'
    ],

    permalinks: {
      structure: ':basename/index.html'
    },

    // Templates
    layoutdir: opt.layouts,
    partials: opt.layouts + '/partials/*.hbs',
    layout: 'default.hbs',

    // data: opt.data + '/*.{json,yml}',
    // assets: opt.dev + '/assets',

    sitemap: {
      homepage: opt.homepage,
      changefreq: 'monthly',
      priority: '0.8',
      robot: false,
      relativedest: true
    },

  },

  pages: {
    files: [
      {
        src: opt.pages + '/*.{hbs,md}',
        dest: opt.dev + '/'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've got it working:

The problem was that the v0.4.0 and greater of assemble-middlewear-permalinks requires Assmble v0.5.0 which is not yet ready for public use (see: https://github.com/assemble/assemble-middleware-permalinks and https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble).

The fix was to install assemble-**contrib**-permalinks (v0.3.6) and use this instead. I've also updated the assemble task code for others who might come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears on the readme that you would actually want to use the following:

```
...
permalinks: {
      structure: ':basename/index:html'
    },
...
```

As well as, the short cut for this -

```
...
permalinks: {
      preset: 'pretty'
    },
...
```

See if either of those do the trick.

Comment: Tried both, no dice. It's been bothering me that with assemble-middleware-permalinks enabled the assemble task has no output at all, not even "x pages assembled".